# Solving inverse of modulo

Tags: modular-arithmetic, euclidean-algorithm

How can I solve for: $$5^{-1} \mod 3$$ ?

I am having hard time to understand how it is solve so please make it easy for me how it works.

Comment: You don't have 5 in $\Bbb Z_3$, I think.

Comment: @Arthur I never made any distinction between $\mathbb Z_3$ and $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$. For me $5$ is in both cases an abbreviation of $[5]=[2]$. Further an element can have more than one notation. Let me add: this is the way I see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$5^{-1}$ is the number such that if you multiply by $5$, you get $1$. In other words, it's the solution to $5x\equiv 1\pmod 3$.

Modulo $3$, multiplying by $5$ is the same as multiplying by $2$, so $5^{-1}$ is the same as $2^{-1}$.

Now, what number (modulo $3$) is such that if you multiply by $2$, you get $1$? In other words, solve $2x\equiv 1\pmod 3$. There are only three different values that $x$ could have, so try them all, and you will find the answer.

There are ways of actually *finding* this $x$, in case we are working modulo $n$ and $n$ becomes too large to feasibly test every case. Specifically, the extended Euclidean algorithm will let you find $x$ in $O(\log n)$ steps, assuming a solution exists (and if a solution doesn't exist then the algorithm will tell you that too).

Comment: For what it's worth: if $p$ is a prime then the inverse $a^{-1}$ always exists in $\Bbb Z_p$ for each nonzero $a$.

Comment: @Vim And if $n$ is not prime, but $\gcd(a, n) = 1$, then $a^{-1}\pmod n$ has multiple solutions. You're right, I should've mentioned that.

Answer (score 1):

First note $5=2$. Then consider $2\times ?=1$ where you can try $?$ from $0,1,2$. Not a tedious task.